# nav bar dropdown item not positioned properly (html/css)

Tags: html, css

So I've made a simple dropdown menu in HTML/CSS. The problem is visible when I hover/click on the dropdown item ("work" in this example). The item displayed on hover/click doesn't drop down low enough on the horizontally menu or drops too far on the vertical one. I'd love to know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Note: I'm using Eric Meyer's CSS reset v2.0 available here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
It has an effect on how the menu looks/performs but the problem is visible without it.

Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qcdtj85w/

I'm using `@media` to change between the vertical and horizontal versions of the menu so y'all can just change the size of the display window to test both

Thanks!

Here's the code:

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" /><!-- Used to make @media work w iphone -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="menu">      
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Work</a>
            <ul class="noJS">
                <li><a href="#">Drop</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>    
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
#menu,
#menu ul {
    background-color: #000;
    list-style: none;
    top:20px;
}
#menu {
    position:fixed;
    float: left;
}
#menu > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
#menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
#menu ul li a {
    width: 50px;
}
#menu li:hover ul.noJS {
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
}

@media all and (max-width: 860px) { 

    #menu{
        position: fixed;
        top: 20px;
        right: 0px;
    }
    #menu > li {
        float: none;
    }

    #menu > li {
        float: none;
    }

    #menu ul {
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    #menu li:active ul.noJS {
        display: block;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this rule:

```
#menu li:hover ul.noJS {
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
}
```

...add `top: 32px;`

All in all that is:

```
#menu li:hover ul.noJS {
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    top: 32px;
}
```

and in the mobile version (media queries section):

```
#menu li:hover ul.noJS {
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes, This works perfectly with a `top: 0px;` in the `@media` section for the same rule